# Письма идут в спам. Что делать?

Tags: битрикс, email, спам

Письма для восстановления пароля на нашем сайте идут пользователям в спам. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина? Сайт сделан на битриксе

Comment: Посмотреть рекомендации https://support.google.com/a/answer/81126 и от их результата уже действовать, устранять недочеты